# PowerShell Send-MailMessage does not dispose attachment after failing to send

Tags: email, powershell, dispose

I'm having a bit of trouble with my automated Powershell Hyper-V Backup script. The script functions perfectly, but my issue is that when I try to send an email with the log file as attachment, it does not unlock the file after it FAILS to send it. (It's not possible for me to check how it acts, when it send the mail successfully, but to be honest, it should also dispose it, even when it fails to send.)

I have searched throughout the web and all I could find, is that either:

1.) Send-MailMessage automatically dispose attachments, after sending the mail.

2.) Use the method from Powershell v1 with new-object system.net.mail.mailmessage and new-object system.net.mail.attachment.

Heres the part of my code (I have shortened it down to only the essentials of the code needed):

```
[String]$ComputerName = Get-Content Env:ComputerName
[String]$LogFile = "Hyper-V Backup Logs\$ComputerName.Hyper-V Backup." + (Get-Date).Day + "-" +(Get-Date).Month + "-" +(Get-Date).Year + "-" +(Get-Date).Hour + "." +(Get-Date).Minute + "." +(Get-Date).Second + ".log"

"# $(Get-Date) :: Attempting to send log file to 'Support@example.dk'..." | Out-File $LogFile -Append
Try
{
    $EmailTo = "Support@example.dk"
    $EmailFrom = "Service@example.dk"
    $EmailServer = "server.example.dk"
    $EmailSubject = "An error occurred during Hyper-V Backup on $ComputerName!"
    $EmailBody = "Hello,

    An error occured during Hyper-V Backup on $ComputerName.
        
    I have attached the log file, $LogFile, to this mail.

    Kind Regards,<br></p>
    Hyper-V Backup.
    "
        
    Send-MailMessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $EmailSubject -Body $EmailBody -Attachments $LogFile -SmtpServer $EmailServer
    "# $(Get-Date) :: Successfully send log file to 'Support@example.dk" | Out-File $LogFile -Append

}
Catch
{
    "# $(Get-Date) :: Failed to send log file to 'Support@example.dk" | Out-File $LogFile -Append
    "                      :: Error Command: Send-MailMessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $EmailSubject -Body $EmailBody -Attachments $LogFile -SmtpServer $EmailServer" | Out-File $LogFile -Append
    "                      :: Error Message: $($_.Exception.Message)" | Out-File $LogFile -Append
}
```

Which throws the following error:

```
Out-File : The process cannot access the file 'C:\Hyper-V Backup\Hyper-V Backup
Logs\example.Hyper-V Backup.22-8-2013-13.48.16.log' because it is being used by
another process.
At C:\Hyper-V Backup\Hyper-V Backup.ps1:310 char:163
+ ... port@example.dk" | Out-File $LogFile -Append
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

How can I make Send-MailMessage dispose the attachment, after failing to send the email, so my script can continue to write to the log file?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've handled it and it seems to be working for me:

```
 try {
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    $SmtpSettings = @{
        To = $Recipients.Split(',')
        From = $Sender
        SmtpServer = $SmtpServer
        Subject = "Email test"
        Body = "Please check attached file"
        Attachment = $Attachment
    }
    Send-MailMessage @SmtpSettings -BodyAsHtml
 } catch {
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
    [gc]::collect()
    $CustomError = ($_ -replace "`r`n","")
    $ScriptLine = "$($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)" +','+ "$($_.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine)"
    Write-Verbose "Error sending email: $CustomError (script line $ScriptLine)"
}
```

I've basically used garbage collector - **[gc]::collect()** and it unlocked the attachement file despite the error while sending an email. 
I've also set **$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'** in **try** so it would catch the error properly and **$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'** inside of **catch** so the script would not stop completelly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this old style. Works fine for me.

```
#Send Email
$smtpServer = "10.10.10.10"
$file = "C:\Temp\TEST.zip"
$att = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($file)
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg.From = "MYNAME@DOMAIN.com"
$msg.To.Add("yourname@domian.com")
$msg.CC.Add("yourname2@domain.com")
$msg.Subject = "Subject here"
$msg.Body = "Body here"
$msg.Attachments.Add($att)
$smtp.Send($msg)
$att.Dispose()
```